# Working of Resource Injection @Resource and Spring Framework?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, annotations

I want to understand how the annotation works. I have this piece of code which I have used in a simple Spring project.

```
@Resource(name="dataSource")
private DataSource dataSouce;
```

The dataSource I have defined in an XML config file:

```
<!-- The Apache DBCP implementation of DataSource -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test"/>
        <property name="username" value="sa"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>
```

Other snippet from spring xml config file

```
    <context:annotation-config /> <!-- This enables the annotation's actions, else annotations don't do their work. -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.dao.jdbc.impl"/> <!-- This is for component scan -->
    <bean id="jdbcOperImpl" class="com.example.dao.jdbc.impl.JdbcOperImpl"/>
```

As I understand the Resource annotations comes from `javax.annotation.Resource`. I looked its [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/annotation/Resource.java), and I notices the annotation is defined by JDK SE, and it is just a simple definition of an annotation. How does this do the injection? Does Spring Framework use this annotation and does Injection? How is `@Resource` annotation and Spring framework related?

Comment: Possible duplicate of these two: [@Resource vs @Autowired](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4093504/476716) and [What is dependency injection?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/130794/476716)

Comment: What exactly are you asking? There's a good chance this question is either too broad or a duplicate.

Comment: *"Do Spring Framework use this annotation and does Injection?"* Yes, most if not all annotations are just simple markers that carry information for units that process them.

Comment: @OrangeDog: This question isn't duplicate of the question that you have hinted at. I am asking how does Resource inject the dependency. I looked at the source code of Resouce annotation and there is nothing special in that code which might inject the dependency.  I was asking what is the relation between Resouce and the spring framework when it comes injecting the dependency (how exactly these two work together for injecting the dependency)

Comment: Then it's a duplicate of [How does dependency injection work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3725515/476716)

Comment: @OrangeDog I would say no again! I am specific to Resouce annotation and Spring here. The other SO are "how" DI works. I would see if I can do some more research of my own. I thank you for your help.

Comment: That question is Spring-specific and exactly what you're asking. As the first question I suggested says, `Resource` works just the same in this respect as `Autowired` and `Inject`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually Spring supports two types of annotations which are Spring based annotations and Java based annotations. For dependencies you can use @Autowired that completely spring annotations.

@Resource and @Inject are the standard java based annotations. For more clarity see this link http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2011/08/spring-injection-with-resource-and-autowired/